# Managing sphinx for multiple websites

Tags: php, cron, sphinx, centos5, indexer

I have a few sites that use Sphinx Search indexes, which are fundamental to their running. This however has a massive impact on the amount of indexing I have to do on my server. I currently have a cron job that runs every 24 hours to reindex my database. This has to run approximately 15 different sources which all average around 100,000 rows in my database. So quite hefty...

I've recently had no issues with running indexer --all --rotate on my sphinx.conf, however I just discovered my log files (over the past 6 months ) have grown over 10GBs. These files specifically are /var/log/query.log and /var/log/searchd.log.

This is obviously not the best of situations. Therefore I was hoping to get my self in a position whereby I could separate the sets on indexes I have between my websites so I don't have to do such a gigantic call on one beefy sphinx.conf file.

At least this way I can be flexible with my cron indexing as Site 1 may not need to be indexed as much as Site 3, for example. I can also separate my log files this way too.

Answer (score 2):

You dont NEED to use `--all`, can instead just name the index(es) you wish to rotate on the command line.

As for large log files, logrotate is your friend

- http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html
- http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=tips_and_tricks#log_rotation

(would recommend this over trying to run multiple instances of sphinx, while possible quickly gets messy)